# i want to use raspberry pi as a router to access zigbee end devices

Tags: home-automation

I connected raspberry pi to tv to use as minicomputer and I have installed raspberry operating system in raspberry pi kit.My intension is to use raspberry pi as router and it has to communicate with the zigbee end devices and i need your help to continue my work

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Zigbee module (SPI or I2C : May be something like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/digi-international/xbp24-z7uit-004/zigbee-mod-xbee-pro-zb-u-fl-conn/dp/1751799)) and a custom middle ware to bridge your wifi / LAN and Zigbee enabled devices.